# How to retrieve custom annotation fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I would like to implement a custom annotation that could be applied to a class (once inside an app), to enable a feature (Access to remote resources). If this annotation is placed on any config class, it will set the access for the whole app. So far it isn't that hard (see example below), but I want to include some definition fields in the `@interface` that will be used in the access establishing process.

As an example, Spring has something very similar: `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Access is enabled to the DB, with parameters in the annotation containing definitions. For example: `@EnableJpaRepositories(bootstrapMode = BootstrapMode.DEFERRED)`

So far, I have:

To create only the access I'm using something like that:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(AccessHandlerConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableAccessHandlerAutoconfigure {
    String name() default "";
}
```

Using it:

```
@EnableAccessHandlerAutoconfigure{name="yoni"}
@Configuration
public class config {}
```

`AccessHandlerConfiguration` is a configuration class that contains beans that establish the connection.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to retrieve the field name's value. What should I do?

Comment: this.getClass().getAnnotation(EnableAccessHandlerAutoconfigure.class).name() should work

Comment: @voidvoid thx, where can I put this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I found a way: There is a method in Spring's `ApplicationContext` that retrieves bean names according to their annotations `getBeanNamesForAnnotation`, then get the annotation itself `findAnnotationOnBean`, and then simply use the field getter.

```
@Configuration
public class AccessHandlerConfiguration {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public AccessHandlerConfiguration(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;        
        String[] beansWithTheAnnotation = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(EnableRabbitAutoconfigure.class);

        for (String beanName : beansWithTheAnnotation) {
            EnableRabbitAutoconfigure annotationOnBean = applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, EnableRabbitAutoconfigure.class);
            System.out.println("**********" + beanName + "*********************" + annotationOnBean.name() + "*******************");
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
**********config*********************yoni*******************
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the value may be accomplished as follows:

```
this.getClass().getAnnotation(EnableAccessHandlerAutoconfigure.class).name()
```

To expand on my comment with an actual example configuration class that uses this:

```
@EnableAccessHandlerAutoconfigure(name="yoni")
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {
    @Bean
    SomeBean makeSomeBean() {
        return new SomeBean(this.getClass().getAnnotation(EnableAccessHandlerAutoconfigure.class).name());
    }
}
```

This is how you get the value of name, as to what you are going to do next, that depends on you.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't really answer my question. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. It is not very helpful to retrieve the field in the same class because it is anyway hardcoded at the top (it could simply be a `final String`, and this complicated solution is unnecessary). I looked for a way to get this data in the code module of the implementation of the custom field.

Comment: Yes, I did find that strange, but just thought I would answer the question as I understood it. If the annotation is on a component you could also autowire it and access the annotation values in your module with bean.getClass().getAnnotation...

Comment: Thank you, meanwhile, I found a solution, please have a look at my answer.